# Read strongly typed yaml file in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, yaml

I have the following `yaml` file:

```yaml
trainingPhrases:
- help me
- what to do
- how to play
- help
```

I readi it from disk using `readFile` from node and parse it using `load` from `js-yaml`:

```js
import { load } from "js-yaml";
import { readFile } from "fs/promises";

const phrases = load(await readFile(filepath, "utf8")).trainingPhrases as string[];
```

I get the following `eslint` warning:

```
ESLint: Unsafe member access .trainingPhrases on an any value.(@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access)
```

Instead of suppressing the warning, I would like to map it into a concrete type for the YAML file (as it happens in axios for example: `axios.get<MyResponseInterface>(...)` - performs a `GET` and `MyResponseInterface` defines the structure of the HTTP response).

Is there a dedicated library for that?

Comment: What do you mean by *"concrete type for the YAML file (as it happens in axios for example)."*?

Comment: @Yoshi that I define structure as interfaces in TS - in axios it looks like: `axios.get<MyResponseInterface>(...)` where `MyResponseInterface` is interface defined by me and it reflects structure of the response

Comment: I'm not used to the node functions, so I can't say if say accept a type parameter. But you could simply declare phrases to be of the correct type. Have you tried that? E.g. `const phrases: YourType = ...`. (At least I'm assuming it's node, otherwise, you'd need to explain where `load` and `readFile` are from).

Comment: @yoshi I added imports

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I can see when using [`@types/js-yaml`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/js-yaml) is that `load` is not generic, meaning it does not accept a type parameter.

So the only way to get a type here is to use an assertion, for example:

```
const yaml = load(await readFile(filepath, "utf8")) as YourType;
const phrases = yaml.trainingPhrases;
```

Or in short:

```
const phrases = (load(await readFile(filepath, "utf8")) as YourType).trainingPhrases;
```

---

If you absolutely want a generic function, you can easily wrap the original, like:

```
import {load as original} from 'js-yaml';

export const load = <T = ReturnType<typeof original>>(...args: Parameters<typeof original>): T => load(...args);
```

And then you can use it as:

```
const phrases = load<YourType>('....').trainingPhrases;
```

Comment: do you know if there is yaml parsing library that has generics?

Comment: No I don't. But I don't think it's relevant. The conformity to the type can't and won't be *validated* at runtime anyways (just like with axios). Thus even one that uses generics will probably only pass that type so the method has a *configurable* return type. In the end, this means you're responsible, and at that point it's perfectly valid to use a type assertion.